I think my cats in labor. Is she ok?
My cat is 3 years old she got outside a little while ago and got pregnant. I'm not sure the exact date of conception but I think she might be in labor. It sounds goofy but I didn't realize she was pregnant until about 2 weeks ago when I was feeling her belly and felt them move. At first, I just thought she was getting fat.
I think she might be going into labor now. I noticed some little spots of blood in areas where she was sitting and that was a few hours ago. It looks like she might be having contractions here and there. She doesn't seem to be in any distress but she doesn't want me touching her belly so I'm not. I made a few different spots for her to choose from but she doesn't seem interested in any of them; she's just staying on my bed stand.
It's very important that I mention not only is she small for her age but she also has a small umbilical hernia that she was born with. It hasn't given her any issues and it seems to have gotten even smaller during her pregnancy.
Is this something I should be concerned about? I can't afford a vet but if this is an emergency as much as I'd hate to I'm concerned about surrendering her.

I am not an expert, as the most people here. So if you are in worry about thr health of your cat, ask a vet! Don't wait for strangers from the internet to answer. You can try to call a vet and ask at the phone, or send a picture to the vet. Some do this kind of service for a lower price. I wish your cat the best! I assume you read a lots of information about how owners can help their cats with getting kittens.

I'm also not an expert, but I don't see anything too concerning here. Usually instincts take over and nature does what it always does. You should make sure the place where your cat decides to give birth is calm and undisturbed and you might want to read up on possible complications like milk fever, which can be treated at home if the signs are recognized early. Your cat mom will also require more nutrients while lactating, so switching her to kitten food for a while is a good idea.
